# Get image from a wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, image, post

i have the title of my last 4 posts but i need the image post too. I'm terrible programmer `

```
include('../blog/wp-load.php'); // Blog path

// Get the last 4 posts
  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
  'numberposts' => 4,
  'category' => 0,
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
));

// Display them as list
echo '<ul>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
  echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>'`
```

i'm trying to do something like this:

[image: Recent Post]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
<ul>
<?php
include('esenergy/wp-load.php'); // Blog path
function recentPosts() {
    $rPosts = new WP_Query();
    $rPosts->query('showposts=3');
        while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('recent-thumbnails'); ?></a>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
            </li>   
        <?php endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>
</ul>
<?php echo recentPosts(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `get_the_post_thumbnail` Here's the [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/).

For example:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $postID,'medium', array( 'class' => 'aligncenter' ));
```

You might try something like this for your final product (untested):

```
// Display them as list

$output = '<ul>';

foreach($recent_posts as $post) {

$link = get_permalink($post['ID']);
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $postID,'medium', array( 'class' => 'aligncenter' ));
$title = $post['post_title'];

$output .= '<li>
                <a href="'.$link.'">'.
                    $image
                    .'<h2>'.$title.'</h2>
                </a>
            </li>';

}
$output .= '</ul>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: I added a more complicated (but also easier!) solution you could test. 

You can also just do `echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $postID,'medium', array( 'class' => 'aligncenter' ));` --- if you read the Codex, you'll find you can specify HTML using `get_the_post_thumbnail` (as I have done in the example).

Comment: didn't work too! Source code: `<ul>
 <li><a href="http://localhost/server/esenergy/meu-post/"><h2>My post</h2></a></li>
...
</ul>`

Comment: You may need to tinker a bit. I see one possible issue - you're using ` $postID` for the function but that value isn't defined. Try ` $post['ID']`. Also - see if there are examples of `wp_get_recent_posts` and `get_the_post_thumbnail` out there.

Answer (score 1):

It's must be work!

```
<?php

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
                    'numberposts' => 4,
                    'category' => 0,
                    'orderby' => 'post_date',
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
));

foreach($recent_posts as $single_post){
    $get_post_images = get_attached_media( 'image', $single_post['ID'] );
    $get_post_images = array_shift( $get_post_images );
    $first_image_url = $get_post_images->guid;


?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($single_post['ID']) ?>"><?php echo $single_post['post_title'] ?></a><br />  
<img src="<?php echo $first_image_url; ?>" /><br />

<?php    
}

?>
```

Comment: Worked!! but 2 posts is not showing the image. Look -> http://i.imgur.com/Fjs06HR.png All images are .JPG

Comment: Have you in this two posts images inside? If this posts have only thumbnail image then this code need to modificate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have't the post thumbnail, but have images inside post, then you need this solution which use inside the loop:

```
$get_post_images = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
$get_post_images = array_shift( $get_post_images );

//Get url for image
$first_image_url = $get_post_images->guid;

// Show the image
echo '<img src="'. $first_image_url .'" />';
```

Comment: Hello buddy! didn't work.. `<img src="" /><h2>My first post</h2>`

Comment: Maybe try that: <img src="<?php echo $first_image_url; ?>" /><h2>My first post</h2> and put above this code - <?php $get_post_images = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID ); $get_post_images = array_shift( $get_post_images ); $first_image_url = $get_post_images->guid; ?>